# Uniformly respond to publication errors

Tags: meteor

Let's say I have a pretty simple publication.

```
Meteor.publish('players', function (guildId) {
  if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'player', guildId)) {
    return Meteor.users.find({
      [`roles.${guildId}`]: 'player'
    });
  } else {
    this.error(new Meteor.Error(401, "Unauthorized"));
  }
});
```

I have a few of these. What I am wondering is: can I respond to the codes that I give out in some particular way? Eg:

```
OnErrorHooks({
  400: function (err) {
    BlazeLayout.render('Error', {
      content: err.message
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```js
var hooks = {
    400: function (err) {
        BlazeLayout.render('Error', {
            content: err.message
        });
    }
}

handleErrors = function(error) {
    var handler hooks[Number(error.error)];
    if (handler) {
        handler(error);
    } else {
        console.log("no error handler defined for error", error);
    }
};

Meteor.subscribe('players', { onStop: handleErrors });
Meteor.subscribe('games', { onStop: handleErrors });
...
```

If your question is whether there is a way around having to add the `{ onStop: handlerErrors }` to each subscription, then I would guess no, but of course you could write a convenience function for that, too:

```js
mySubscribe = function(sub) {
    Meteor.subscribe(sub, { onStop: handleErrors });
};
```